# Managing container dependencies on startup

Tags: docker, containers, supervisord, orchestration, etcd

I have the following setup:

- PostgreSQL
- Flyway for it
- Application

I need to chain them in the following manner: Flyway waits for DB to start up, App waits for flyway to finish the migrations.

I thought about using `etcd` to post some keys to it and other containers wait for them. So, basically, entrypoint for each of container should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
status=1
while $status != 0; do
    for kv in $DEPENDENT_KEYS:
       # curl to etcd, get the key
       if $value == true then
         status = 0;
       else 
         status = 1;
       fi;
done;

# container-related startup
# post to etcd that container is ready
# get back to _container-related startup_
```

My questions are:

1) Am I doing it right?

2) How can I detach from process and then reattach to it without installing much extra utilities (assuming I use busybox/debian as base image)

P.S. I thought of supervisord, it's close, but I don't know how to make processes wait there (and chain them)
P.P.S. All the setup is intended to be executed by Docker Compose.

Comment: Have a look at runit, s6, daemontools ?